# Unable to compile bnull-transform.c - Apache Traffic Server

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, apache-traffic-server

I am trying to run bnull-transform example of Apache traffic server. After a making few changes which are not present on github version of the code, I was finally able to resolve the errors. But when I compile it using gcc I am getting the below errors -

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to`main'
/tmp/cc5gVORu.o: In function `my_data_alloc':
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to`_TSmalloc'
/tmp/cc5gVORu.o: In function `my_data_destroy':
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x7b): undefined reference to`TSIOBufferDestroy'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `_TSfree'
/tmp/cc5gVORu.o: In function`handle_buffering':
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0xa8): undefined reference to `TSVConnWriteVIOGet'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to`TSIOBufferCreate'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0xe7): undefined reference to `_TSAssert'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0xf9): undefined reference to`TSIOBufferReaderAlloc'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x122): undefined reference to `_TSAssert'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x130): undefined reference to`TSVIOBufferGet'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x155): undefined reference to `TSVIONTodoGet'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x16e): undefined reference to`TSVIOReaderGet'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x176): undefined reference to `TSIOBufferReaderAvail'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x19f): undefined reference to`TSVIOReaderGet'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x1bd): undefined reference to `TSIOBufferCopy'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x1cf): undefined reference to`TSVIOReaderGet'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x1da): undefined reference to `TSIOBufferReaderConsume'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x1e6): undefined reference to`TSVIONDoneGet'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x1ff): undefined reference to `TSVIONDoneSet'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x20b): undefined reference to`TSVIONTodoGet'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x222): undefined reference to `TSVIOContGet'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x233): undefined reference to`TSContCall'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x24b): undefined reference to `TSVIOContGet'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x25c): undefined reference to`TSContCall'
/tmp/cc5gVORu.o: In function `handle_output':
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x294): undefined reference to`TSTransformOutputVConnGet'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x2a8): undefined reference to `TSIOBufferReaderAvail'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x2c6): undefined reference to`TSVConnWrite'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x2ef): undefined reference to `_TSAssert'
/tmp/cc5gVORu.o: In function`handle_transform':
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x315): undefined reference to `TSContDataGet'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x341): undefined reference to`TSContDataSet'
/tmp/cc5gVORu.o: In function `bnull_transform':
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x3b0): undefined reference to`TSVConnClosedGet'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x3c0): undefined reference to `TSContDataGet'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x3d4): undefined reference to`TSContDestroy'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x3f1): undefined reference to `TSVConnWriteVIOGet'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x401): undefined reference to`TSVIOContGet'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x412): undefined reference to `TSContCall'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x420): undefined reference to`TSTransformOutputVConnGet'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x432): undefined reference to `TSVConnShutdown'
/tmp/cc5gVORu.o: In function`transformable':
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x46a): undefined reference to `TSHttpTxnServerRespGet'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x47d): undefined reference to`TSHttpHdrStatusGet'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x49b): undefined reference to `TS_NULL_MLOC'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x4aa): undefined reference to`TSHandleMLocRelease'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x4be): undefined reference to `TSError'
/tmp/cc5gVORu.o: In function`transform_add':
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x4e0): undefined reference to `TSTransformCreate'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x4f9): undefined reference to`TSHttpTxnHookAdd'
/tmp/cc5gVORu.o: In function `transform_plugin':
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x54e): undefined reference to`TSHttpTxnReenable'
/tmp/cc5gVORu.o: In function `TSPluginInit':
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x59c): undefined reference to`TSPluginRegister'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x5af): undefined reference to `TSError'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x5bf): undefined reference to`TSError'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x5d2): undefined reference to `TSContCreate'
bnull-transform.c:(.text+0x5df): undefined reference to`TSHttpHookAdd'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compile this plugin (which is a .so) as a standalone app. That won't work. You should use the tsxs script that comes with your ATS installation, e.g.

```
tsxs -o null-transform.so null-transform.cc
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing, you must have found it before if you tried to compile it as above (which wouldn't work). It's built as part of the standard build if you do

    ./configure --enable-example-plugins